# as.numeric is rounding positive values / outputing NA for negative values

Tags: r, numeric

I am trying to do something with [R] which should be extremely simple: convert values in a data.frame to numbers, as I need to test for their values and r does not recognize them as number.

When I convert a decimal number to numeric, I get the correct value:

```
> a <- as.numeric(1.2)
> a
[1] 1.2
```

However, when I extract a positive value from the data.frame then use as.numeric, the number is rounded up:

```
> class(slices2drop)
[1] "data.frame"
> slices2drop[2,1]
[1] 1.2
Levels: 1 1.2
> a <- as.numeric(slices2drop[2,1])
> a
[1] 2
```

Just in case:

```
> a*100
[1] 200
```

So this is not a problem with display, the data itself is not properly handled.

Also, when the number is negative, I get NA:

```
> slices2drop[2,1] <- -1
> a <- as.numeric(slices2drop[2,1])
> a
[1] NA
```

Any idea as to what may be happening?

Comment: Note that the first time you show us slices2drop[2,1] it returns a factor.  That is your issue - you're working with a factor - not numeric data.

Comment: See `?factor`, **Warning** section.

Comment: Please take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418128/how-to-convert-a-factor-to-an-integer-numeric-without-a-loss-of-information

Answer (score 11):

This problem has to do with `factors`. To solve your problem, first coerce your factor variable to be character and then apply `as.numeric` to get what you want.

```
> x <- factor(c(1, 1.2, 1.3)) # a factor variable
> as.numeric(x)  
[1] 1 2 3
```

Integers number are returned, one per each level, there are 3 levels: `1, 1.2` and `1.3`, therefore `1,2,3` is returned.

```
> as.numeric(as.character(x)) # this is what you're looking for
[1] 1.0 1.2 1.3
```

Actually `as.numeric` is not rounding your numbers, it returns a unique integer per each level in your factor variable.

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar situation where the conversion of factor into numeric would generate incorrect results.

When you type: **?factor**

The ***Warning*** mentioned with the factor variables explains this complexity very well and provides the solution to this problem as well.
It's a good place to start working with...

Another thing to consider is that, such conversion would transform ***NULL***s into ***NA***s